# If user DM bot, bot must post that message to a specified room (Hangouts Chat)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hangouts, hangouts-api

This is the code which I got from the template

```
function onMessage(event) {
  var name = "";

  if (event.space.type == "DM") {
    name = "You";
  } else {
    name = event.user.displayName;
  }
  var message = name + " said \"" + event.message.text + "\"";

  return { "text": message };
```

And when i DM the bot, it replies correctly and even when added to a room and it is mentioned via @bot_name, it responds correctly.
But I want this functionality
if i message the bot via DM, it should post that message in a specific chat room.
How do i edit the above function to get the bot to post the message to a specific chat room?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Some context may help give an alternative solution. That said, according to the docs you can't, all the information is [here](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/concepts/bots). Though with [webhooks](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/webhooks) you may find an alternative.

Comment: @iansedano I want to build a bot for my organization where if they dm the bot with any message, it should post that message in the official chat room anonymously. It is to provide a way for employees to anonymously post something or discuss something without divulging their identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do it via a webhook call. There seems to be no way of doing it via any other way that I know of or that the document reads.

```
var message = " Someone says \"" + event.message.text + "\"";
var url = "<Webhook_URL>";
  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'contentType' : 'application/json',
    'payload' : JSON.stringify({
      "text": message
    })
  };
UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

For more information about webhooks, please refer to this [URL](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/webhooks)